# PowerShell: Unable to check if display name exists within email address and reverse display name's firstname + lastname

Tags: powershell

I need to check if a display name exists is within an email address and reverse its lastname + firstname in-case it's backwards.

Let's assume the email address is `test.user@email.com` and the display name is `user test`.

I need to check if the display name exists within the email address and if `firstname` and `lastname` are reversed compared to the email address reverse it so it complies with the email address' firstname + lastname schema.

I don't even know where to start. Should I split the email address on `.` and `@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how you might do it for a single name.  You will need to re-work it into some kind of loop or make a function out of it, if you have lots of names/addresses to check.

```
$userName = "User Test"
$nameParts = $userName.Split(' ')

$userEmail = "test.user@email.com"

if($userEmail -eq "$($nameparts[1]).$($nameParts[0])@email.com")
{
    "'$userEmail' is a valid email for '$userName'"
}
else
{
    "'$userEmail' is NOT a valid email for '$userName'"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution to getting the name but you could do something like this

```
$address = "first.second@mymail.com"
$Name=$Address.Split("@")[0]
```

Then check if $Name is correctly formatted and if it is not split it with

```
$firstname = $Name.Split(".")[0]
$secondname = $Name.Split(".")[1]
$swapped = $secondname+"."+ $firstname
```

And check again and if correct rebuild the email address

```
$domain=$Address.Split("@")[1]
$emailaddress = $swapped +"@" + $domain
$emailaddress
```

Like I said maybe not the best way but it should give you some idea

Comment: You can split and assign the parts of the name in a single command: `$firstname, $secondname = $Name.Split(".")`